# Bitmap Converting to 3.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, bitmap

just a quick question working with MS Visual Studio 2010 and i get this error

```
error RC2170: bitmap file C:\Users\Doug\Desktop\paperbowser.bmp is not in 3.00 format
```

how can i get this bitmap into 3.0 format

thanks

Answer (score 3):

http://www.coolutils.com/online/image-converter/

Just go to the above link and convert your image file to .bmp file.